# How to use SSO for PWA?

Tags: single-sign-on, manifest.json

Is it possible to use SSO for PWAs for standalone display?

I can login to my app through email but if I try twitter/fb/google SSO, it opens to a new browser since they are out of the scope.  This makes it pretty useless...

Is the only solution to just wrap the app?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, SSO-inside-an-installed-PWA is broken on Chrome for Desktop as of Chrome 70 (November 2018).

The good news is, the W3C web.manifest standard has changed, and [will no longer require browsers to open out-of-scope navigation in a separate window](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/449#issuecomment-435217874). This will fix the case of installed PWAs with single-sign-on authentication. This will be fixed in Chrome 71 on the desktop (due December 2018), and is already fixed on Chrome for Android.

Here's the [update to the W3C web.manifest spec](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/pull/701) that details the change. In short, the spec says browsers must not block out-of-scope navigation inside an installed PWA. Instead, the spec encourages browsers to show some prominent UI (perhaps a bar at the top) notifying the user that the navigation is out-of-scope.

> "Unlike previous versions of this specification, user agents are no
>   longer required or allowed to block off-scope navigations, or open
>   them in a new top-level browsing context. This practice broke a lot of
>   sites that navigate to a URL on another origin..."

Comment: Is it still broken on Chrome?

Comment: I believe this was fixed in Chrome 71 (early 2019).